ReactJS updating array values through checkbox list
So i have a checklist that i want to have a date pop up as a timestamp next to it when it is checked and if it is unchecked go back to the default value which is '-'. I created a default array, then used that to determine the main array which is timeVars, then use the checkbox update code to update the timeVars array values.
The code i have written out sorta works, but its only editing the one index of the list item and changing all of the previous values back to the default, which is not what i want to do.
const defaulttimeVars = ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']; 
const [timeVars, setTimeVars] = useState(defaulttimeVars);

these come first - set when the app runs, then here is the checkbox control:
const handleChange = (curVal,index) => {
  let defaulttimeVars = timeVars;
  
  let editVal = '';
  let updateArray = [];

 updateArray = defaulttimeVars.map((c, i) => {

//this auto loops through each index
//it needs to check current index and only make an edit to the current index, not the remainder.  
//right now, its supposed to curVal.e === '-' and if that is true update that '-' to the current date, if it is not a '-' then change it to a '-'
//then for everything else its supposed to save as whatever the curVal is

editVal = '';

            if (index.e2 === i){

                  if(curVal.e === '-'){

                    editVal = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(Date.now());
                    return editVal

                  }else{

                    return '-';

                  }
                
                }else{
                
                  return curVal.e;


              }
            
  });

  setTimeVars(updateArray);


}


so i reworked it and finally got it updating correctly.  here is the changes to the main handleChange query:
  const handleChange = (curVal,index) => {
  let defaulttimeVars = timeVars;
  
  let editVal = '-';

  const updateArrayVal = defaulttimeVars.map((c, i) => {

//this auto loops through each index
//it needs to check current index and only make an edit to the current index, not the remainder.  
//right now, its supposed to curVal.e === '-' and if that is true update that - to the current date, if it is not a - then change it to a -
//then for everything else its supposed to save as whatever the curVal is
editVal = timeVars[i];

                if(i === index.e2 && curVal.e != '-'){
                  console.log('index is ' + i + ' and current value is ' + editVal + ' so new array should alter ' + i + ' to -')
                  editVal = '-';
                  return editVal;


                }else if (i != index.e2 && editVal != '-'){
                  console.log('index ' + i + ' is not the current check ' + index.e2 + ' and current ' + editVal + ' is not - so new index value should remain as ' + defaulttimeVars[i])
                  editVal = timeVars[i]
                  return editVal;

                }else if (i === index.e2 && curVal.e === '-'){
                  console.log('index matches check ' + i + ' and current value is ' + editVal + ' so value needs to change to ' + new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(Date.now()))

                  editVal = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(Date.now());
                  return editVal;

                }else{
                  editVal = timeVars[i]
                  return editVal
                }
      
  });
  
  setTimeVars(updateArrayVal)



}

